# Error in adapter

Tags: c#

how can I find a number in web page.
Let me to take an example:

for example, if I wanna to find 1234 from following numbers, it just show me the 1234, not 123412(which is including 1234).

1234124 -
113412 -
352523434653 -
1234

I wrote the following code, How can i change it to get my result from it?

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string url = "http://play.dcc.fc.up.pt:2241/PTECH/recommenders/music/<userid>?groups=<userid>";
                var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row["UserID"]));
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
                string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://play.dcc.fc.up.pt:2241/PTECH/recommenders/music/UserID?groups=UserID");
                if (client.Contains(Convert.ToString(TrackID)))
```

Comment: Hi. I think the developer with other programming language can help me to figure this problem out

Comment: You need to search the text string you retrieve for a sequence of characters like this:  `(nondigit)1234(nondigit)`  `Contains` isn't quite smart enough to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use spam tags.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression that sets some sort of boundary before/after the value should work fine. I.e. word boundary `\b` will let you pick number if it have spaces/other separators around it (don't forget to check if match found when using it):

```
 var value = Regex.Matches("foo,1234 bar", @"\b1234\b")[0].Value;
```

Check [Regular Expression Language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  for more options.